# How to recursively find a .doc file that contains a specific word?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, cat

I'm using bash under Ubuntu.

Currently this works well for the current directory:

```
catdoc *.doc | grep "specificword"
```

But I have lots of subdirectories with .doc files.

How can I search for, let's say, "specificword" recursively?

Comment: and maybe also return the name of the file that contains the word?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `find` for recursive searches:

```
find -name '*.doc' -exec catdoc {} + | grep "specificword"
```

This will also output the file name:

```
find -name '*.doc' | while read -r file; do
    catdoc "$file" | grep -H --label="$file" "specificword"
done
```

<sub>(Normally I would use `find ... -print0 | while read -rd "" file`, but there's maybe a .0001% chance that it would be necessary, so I stopped caring.)</sub>

Comment: Thanks grawity, the first suggestion works quit well. Is there a way to print the file name? it's only printing the phrase in which it has been found.

Comment: @user: Try the second suggestion, which, by the way, is titled "This will also output the file name".

Comment: can probably simplify a bit: `find -name \*.doc -exec sh -c "catdoc '{}' | grep -q 'specificword' && echo {}" \;`

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look at [recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) which is a full-text search tool for Linux and Unix systems supporting many different document formats.
However, it is index-based, i.e., it has to index the documents you want to search in before the actual search. (Thanks to pabouk for pointing this out).

There is a GUI and a command line, too.

See the [documentation](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/usermanual/usermanual.html) for further infos.

Comment: Maybe it is worth to note that Recoll provides indexed search. First it has to index the documents then it can search through the indexes.

Answer (score 2):

Grep should find binary matches with:

```
find /path/to/dir -name '*.doc' exec grep -l "specificword" {} \;
```